# error in ie9 changing div content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer-9

the page works in firefox, chrome, and safarie. only breaks in ie9

SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.5.1rc1.js, line 5093 character 5

Comment: update your jQuery to 1.8.3, then let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use jQuery, use it to it's fullest. Remove the `onmouseclick` and `onmouseover` events on each `<a>` node. And add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vids').click(function(){
        var cv = $(this).attr('alt');
        var url = "random.php";
        $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
            $("#myElement").html(data).show();
        });
    });
});
```

The `<a>` nodes need to have an alt attribute with the specific vid and the class `vids`. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="vids" alt="vid1"><img>blabla</img></a>
<a href="#" class="vids" alt="vid2">
<a href="#" class="vids" alt="vid3">
```

You get the point

Comment: i dont thin this even works in other browers because nothing is being alerted anyways..

Comment: i updated jquery to 1.8 i change the function to what u made but now it doesn't work in the other browsers with $("#myElement").html(data).show(); out side the function(data){}

Comment: ok i updated it with the new code still not working in either firefox or ie

Comment: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'swapContent' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
arcticninja, line 54 character 1
SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'swapContent' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
arcticninja, line 54 character 67

Comment: When/where are you actually calling `swapContent(cv)` function ?

Comment: Oh ok makes sense, hold on, I'll edit my original post with the final fix ^_^

Comment: check it out, I added them a class, and cleaned up those event listeners. And added one just for the class `.vids` and it takes their alt attribute and puts in the cv variable.

Comment: i did the updates. the video doesn't change when the link is clicked.

Comment: Alright, this is my last shot, change your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of the long html4 one and make sure the jquery script and your code is the first 2 scripts that are being embed, then it's the jwplayers ones.

Comment: made the changes still no success on any browser.

Comment: where's the links so i can test it

Comment: ya but the <a> links are hidden. that's was the event is attached to.

Comment: the images are the links but i added the link text

Comment: ok cool, your doctype is wrong, it has a `"` that u need to remove. Also, your images are super high res, maybe scaling them down by a lot (thumbnail size) with image editing software will greatly improve page performance.

Comment: ya, i am going to scale down the images when i get this working. ill remove the images to help load time and fix the syntax error

Comment: alright, i edited my javascript code up, it has some debugging stuff so I can track what's going on. please edited it in

Comment: k so it seems to work on every browser to me. You can remove the console.log statements.

Comment: updated the javascript. it seems to be working in all browsers now. thanks a bunch.